# Exception: Cannot load model.bin

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, fasttext

I have got the following error message trying to run a model:

```
Exception: fastText: Cannot load model.bin due to C++ extension failed to allocate the memory
```

The code I have used is the following:

```
import wget
from fasttext import load_model

wget.download("https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/supervised-models/amazon_review_polarity.bin", 'model.bin')

model = load_model("model.bin")
```

I have tried to follow this answer: [FastText - Cannot load model.bin due to C++ extension failed to allocate the memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923279/fasttext-cannot-load-model-bin-due-to-c-extension-failed-to-allocate-the-mem) but probably I am doing something wrong as the error is still there. 
Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: What is the solution that you tried from the link?

Comment: I have tried to install fastText (capital T) from fasttext repo. However I got the same error. From a previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61978549/sentiment-analysis-and-fasttext-import-error/61978758#61978758 I got the above indications on how to run the model. But it seems there is a problem with the load_model function. For my understanding, FastText should be used in case you want analyse Facebook. But in my case are only text (no tweets/posts)

Comment: Your problem probably consists in version mismatch.

Based in my experience, fastText is suitable for any type of text classification task.

Comment: Hi @Anakin87. If you do not mind,could you please tell me which packages(modules, libraries) should I download and the links? I really have no idea why it have not been working. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the latest version of fasttext (0.9.2) following these steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText.git
cd fastText
pip install .
```

then try to execute your code. It should work.